# How to connect with same type 2 servers on different destination from single client by .NET remoting

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, .net-remoting

I have to connect same type of remote objects on different destination using .net remoting. For example, I have a database access middle layer on a remote server and local server. But both are same type object. but the remote destination addresses are different. So how to connect it using .NET Remoting?

Comment: Were you aware that .NET Remoting has been deprecated in favor of WCF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks John Saunders.
I just heard about WCF. Now I move to WCF. It is nice and I solve my problem easily on it.
Thank you very much